# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when shuffling a LinkedList

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list, indexoutofboundsexception

Okay, so I have an assignment and it goes like this:

> Assume you have as input a singly-linked list containing N
>   items (an instance of a LinkedList class in Java). You should rearrange the items in the
>   LinkedList uniformly at random. Your algorithm should consume a logarithmic (or
>   constant) amount of extra memory and run in time proportional to NlogN in the worst
>   case.

For the Algorithm I was going for mergesort which when it merges does so in a random way.
But I have gotten stuck with my program as it throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` but it's not in my code but in LinkedList.java

I'm not very familiar with LinkedList so I have no idea what to do, I'm not even sure I'm doing this in the right way.

The code:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Q02 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(3);
    list.add(4);
    list.add(5);
    list.add(6);
    list.add(7);
    list.add(8);
    list.add(9);
    list.add(0);
    System.out.println("Shuffled list: "+shuffle(list));
}

public static LinkedList shuffle(LinkedList list){
    int node = 10; //just a random node
    if(list.size()<=1){
        return list;
    }
    LinkedList<Integer>list1 = new LinkedList<>();
    LinkedList<Integer>list2 = new LinkedList<>();

    while(!list.isEmpty()){
        list1.add((Integer) list.removeFirst());
        if(!list.isEmpty()){
            list2.add((Integer) list.removeFirst());
        }
    }
    shuffle(list1);
    shuffle(list2);

    if(list2.size() < list1.size()){
        int i = (int)(Math.random() * list2.size());
        list2.set(i, node);
    }

    while(!list1.isEmpty()&&!list2.isEmpty()){
        int rand = (int)(Math.round(Math.random()));
        if(rand == 1){
            list.add(list1.removeFirst());
        }
        else if(rand == 0){
            list.add(list2.removeFirst());
        }
    }
    //If any of list1 or list2 are still empty add everything to list
    if(!list1.isEmpty()){
        list.add(list2.clone());
    }
    if(!list2.isEmpty()){
        list.add(list1.clone());
    }
    list.remove(node);
    return list;
}

}
```

Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 10, Size: 2
at java.util.LinkedList.checkElementIndex(LinkedList.java:553)
at java.util.LinkedList.remove(LinkedList.java:523)
at kth.id2010.lab.lab03.Q02.Q02.shuffle(Q02.java:62)
at kth.id2010.lab.lab03.Q02.Q02.shuffle(Q02.java:39)
at kth.id2010.lab.lab03.Q02.Q02.shuffle(Q02.java:39)
at kth.id2010.lab.lab03.Q02.Q02.shuffle(Q02.java:39)
at kth.id2010.lab.lab03.Q02.Q02.main(Q02.java:22)
```

Comment: Can you show us the error you are getting? Copy/paste the entire stack trace if possible.

Comment: @CoryKlein edited my post, it now includes the error

Comment: Just an unrelated remark: I don't think creating a copy of the input list satisfies the task requirement *algorithm should consume a logarithmic (or constant) amount of extra memory*

Comment: @Durandal It does actualy, since im copying it to 2 different lists the amount of extra memory consumed is logN wich is logarithmic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, that means that somewhere you are trying to access an item in the `LinkedList` using an index that is invalid. For example, if your `LinkedList` has `10` items, then `listOfSize10.set(10, node)` would raise an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Most likely the error you are seeing stems from these lines:

```
int i = (int)(Math.random() * list2.size());
list2.set(i, node);
```

Can you guarantee that `i` is always greater than or equal to `0` and less than `list2.size()`?

**Update**
After seeing your stack trace, it looks like the error comes from these lines:

```
int node = 10; //just a random node
list.remove(node);
```

Here you are clearly trying to remove the item at index `10` (or, the eleventh item) when there are only `10` items in the list. So your array index is out of bounds.

Comment: I thought I could use remove(object) and send the node as the object, but I realise now it will take it as a integer. Is there a way to remove that specific node? since I dont know where it is located

Comment: I haven't tried this, but it might work: `Integer node = 9; list.remove(node);`

Comment: Because `list` is of type `LinkedList<Integer>`, not `LinkedList<int>`.

Comment: I always forget that int and Integer is not the same thing. Thank you that worked, however now my list has 6 slots and only 3 of them have something in them. Any idea why?

Comment: That would probably be appropriate for a separate question.